# Block a command from sudo user

Tags: sudo, root

I don't need an administrator to change my root password. I don't want any sudo user to execute this command:

```
sudo passwd $root
```

I have tried it in the sudoers file using the following command:

```
%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL, !/usr/bin/passwd $root
```

How can I block it?

Comment: Do you mean that you have more than one sudo-able user in your system? Or something else? Please, [edit] the question to provide any new information.

Answer (score 16):

According to [sudoers manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sudoers.5):

```
   It is generally not effective to "subtract" commands from ALL using the
   ’!’ operator.  A user can trivially circumvent this by copying the
   desired command to a different name and then executing that.  For
   example:

       bill        ALL = ALL, !SU, !SHELLS

   Doesn’t really prevent bill from running the commands listed in SU or
   SHELLS since he can simply copy those commands to a different name, or
   use a shell escape from an editor or other program.  Therefore, these
   kind of restrictions should be considered advisory at best (and
   reinforced by policy).
```

This is why your sudoers policy doesn't work.

If you would like to prevent user to gain root permission and change its password, try this procedure:

- Assuming your sudoers contains this directive:

  ```
   root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
   %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
  ```
- Assuming your user name is `foo`, his groups are `foo` and `sudo`. `groups` command output is:

  ```
  foo sudo
  ```
- Remove user `foo` from `sudo` group: `gpasswd -d foo sudo` after this, user `foo` can not run any command with sudo.
- Edit sudoers file. Use this command:

  ```
  sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/foo
  ```
- Define user `foo` permission, for example:

  ```
  foo ALL=/usr/bin, !/usr/bin/passwd, !/usr/bin/su
  ```

  This means that user `foo` may run any commands in the directory `/usr/bin/` except `passwd` and `su` command.
  Note: If the user `foo` wants to change his password, can run `passwd` command without `sudo`.
- Another example of user `foo` permission:

  ```
  foo ALL =/usr/bin, /usr/bin/passwd [A-Za-z]*, !/usr/bin/passwd root
  ```

  This means that user `foo` may run any commands in the directory `/usr/bin/` and is allowed to change anyone’s password except for root on ALL machines.

You can define groups of command by define `Cmnd_Aliases` and create "levels of permissions". You can found useful examples in EXAMPLE section of [sudoers manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/en/man5/sudoers.5.html), and here is a useful [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1132821) about how to use sudoers.

Comment: I had to do `foo ALL=/usr/bin/*, !/usr/bin/passwd` any idea why that's the case?

Comment: this is stupid, you outline the problem, and IMMEDIATELY repeat the same problem...
they can still `sudo cp /usr/bin/su /usr/bin/su2` or `sudo xterm -e su -` or use `sed` to change root's password, etc etc...

Comment: @jan6 instead of offending, you could try giving an answer to the question, this could be more constructive, isn't it? Finally you should read https://ubuntu.com/community/ethos/code-of-conduct

Answer (score -1):

add command alias via `visudo`:

```
Cmnd_Alias PASSWD=/usr/bin/passwd
Cmnd_Alias SU=/bin/su
```

add restrictions via `visudo`:

```
%nopasswdgroup ALL = ALL, !PASSWD, !SU
```

add user to group called nopasswdgroup:

```
usermod -aG nopasswdgroup nopasswduser
```