# Blocking a command from execution in ubuntu

Tags: gnome-terminal, chmod

I have a shared PC with Ubuntu in it, My friends may also want to use sudo.
But I know they often play with the command

```
chmod -R 777 /
```

I need to know is there a way to specifically block this command from execution even by the root user. As no one gonna has to use this command on the usual purpose.

But I may need friends to use chmod on other dirs.

Comment: I simply wouldn't give `sudo` ability to a "friend" who thinks it's fun to wreck my computer. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: See [Block a command from sudo user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500679/block-a-command-from-sudo-user) but note that it's non-trivial to make such measures effective - most obviously, if you don't prevent "other" sudoers from editing the sudoers file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is don't give sudo or root permissions to anybody you don't trust with them.  If it's your computer and they might wreck your machine, then don't give them any elevated permissions, or don't let them use the computer at all.

Comment: If It is not possible to restrict, is there any way to easily recover such thing after the execution of that command?