# Want to restrict a user changing admin password

Tags: 20.04, permissions, 22.04, password

I have two users on a device UserX and user admin using Ubuntu 20.04, both have admin rights, but I want UserX not to be able to change the password of user admin.  However, I still need to be able to allow UserX to install packages\applications and be able to use sudo, etc

Is there a method of restricting UserX rights not to be able to change the useradmin password?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Block a command from sudo user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500679/block-a-command-from-sudo-user)

Answer (score 5):

Since "admin rights" is just access to UID 0, there is no way to restrict UserX.

There is a way to achieve this

- remove "admin rights" from UserX.
- use `sudo` to grant UserX access to specific commands as `root` (UID 0).

Read `man sudo sudoers` to get started.

Comment: Further reading hint: Using sudo would end up with "grant user all except some commands via sudo" (blacklist approach) or "grant user only these specific commands via sudo" (whitelist approach). There are caveats with using the blacklist approach, those are discussed [in this question on U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329405/sudoers-blacklist).

Comment: The safer way to do ANY security thing is "Deny all, allow narrowly defined exceptions".  The other way "Allow all, deny specific hazards as soon as you find out" will have you playing an unending game of Whack-A-Mole, falling ever further behind. BTDT, didn't like it.